# break line issue in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am receiving a comments from service.
If I get this comment "hello world" it is printing as it is but when I receive Comments like this 
"hello

world" then I am receiving nothing I write a function for it but it also doesn't work

```
function NextLineFix(Call) {

        return Call.replace("\n", '<br>');
    }
```

Can any body help please....!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you also have carriage return characters in the string ('\r')? Does this work better for your issue:

```
Call.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "<br/>") ?
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
function NextLineFix(Call) {    
    return Call.replace(/[\r\n]/gi, '<br/>');
}
```

Comment: In this function i am unable to print "" means i want to print the whole text "hello" including "" how can i achieve this can you please solve this????

Comment: try this: return '"' + Call.replace(/[\r\n]/gi, '<br/>') + '"';

Answer (score 0):

Try it with \r\n instead of \n and then do the replace , see if that helps

Comment: Can you check to see what is in call variable? Does it contain the hello world? or does it show unterminated string constant?

Comment: it has "hello world" and remains hello world no change occur